# List Template is not working

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

I have created a list using list template. But, Items are not displaying and it showing the error message as

[image]

Please suggest me the solution how to get the list items. I am using SharePoint 2013 onpremise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok..Are you creating the list in the same site collection? If No, Guess this is an issue with Site columns and the columns in the template is not supported in the site.

If in the same site collection, check the columns which are there in the template, do they have any kind of lookup or calculated columns or managed metadata? Also provide the step you followed to create list from a list template.